# Unity collider prefab doesn't work on one side

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a collider prefab (a cube, with a box collider the size of the cube). In one scene, my player collides perfectly with it, but in another scene, the player glitches and phases through one side of the collider but not the other. Rotating it changes the side that it glitches out on, so it always faces the same global direction.

What could be causing this? I've made sure the prefab for both the player and collider object are exactly the same across scenes, and nothing effects the collisions besides the player controller script which moves the player and has a condition for OnCollisionExit that sets the rigidbody's velocity to 0.

Added the code below. The input is with joysticks (think the joysticks in a helicopter). Like I said, the collision works perfectly usually, but for some reason only in this scene it doesn't. I suspect it's some kind of hierarchy or rigidbody problem but I've checked seemingly everything.

https://github.com/ben-humphries/FRC-Driving-Simulation

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ChassisController : MonoBehaviour {

    public UIController uiController;

    public Canvas PauseCanvas;

    public float speedLinear = 10f;
    public float speedAngular = 100f;
    public float joyDeadZone = 0.5f;

    public float rotationOffset = 3f;

    public bool squaredMovement = false;

    public DriveModes driveMode = DriveModes.Tank;

    [HideInInspector]
    public bool paused = false;


    private Rigidbody rigidbody;

    Vector3 lastLinearPosition;
    float lastAngularPosition;



    void Start () {

        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();

        lastLinearPosition = Vector3.zero;
        lastAngularPosition = 0f;
        paused = false;

    }

    void FixedUpdate () {

        if (!paused) {

            /*
         * INPUT
         */

            if (driveMode == DriveModes.Tank) {


                if (Mathf.Abs (Input.GetAxis ("VerticalLeft")) > joyDeadZone) {


                    Vector3 rotatePoint = (transform.position) + transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.right) * rotationOffset;
                    Vector3 rotateAxis = transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.up);

                    Debug.DrawRay (rotatePoint, rotateAxis * 10f, Color.red);

                    transform.RotateAround (rotatePoint, rotateAxis, -speedAngular * Input.GetAxis ("VerticalLeft") * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (squaredMovement ? Mathf.Abs (Input.GetAxis ("VerticalLeft")) : 1));

                }
                if (Mathf.Abs (Input.GetAxis ("VerticalRight")) > joyDeadZone) {
                    Vector3 rotatePoint = (transform.position) + transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.left) * rotationOffset;
                    Vector3 rotateAxis = transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.up);

                    Debug.DrawRay (rotatePoint, rotateAxis * 10f, Color.red);


                    transform.RotateAround (rotatePoint, rotateAxis, speedAngular * Input.GetAxis ("VerticalRight") * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (squaredMovement ? Mathf.Abs (Input.GetAxis ("VerticalRight")) : 1));

                }


            } else if (driveMode == DriveModes.Mecanum) {


                if (Mathf.Abs (Input.GetAxis ("VerticalRight")) > joyDeadZone) {
                    transform.Translate (Vector3.forward * -speedLinear * Input.GetAxis ("VerticalRight") * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (squaredMovement ? Mathf.Abs (Input.GetAxis ("VerticalRight")) : 1));
                }

                if (Mathf.Abs (Input.GetAxis ("HorizontalRight")) > joyDeadZone) {
                    transform.Translate (Vector3.right * speedLinear / 5f * Input.GetAxis ("HorizontalRight") * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (squaredMovement ? Mathf.Abs (Input.GetAxis ("HorizontalRight")) : 1));
                }

                if (Mathf.Abs (Input.GetAxis ("TwistRight")) > joyDeadZone) {
                    transform.Rotate (0, speedAngular * Input.GetAxis ("TwistRight") * Time.fixedDeltaTime * (squaredMovement ? Mathf.Abs (Input.GetAxis ("TwistRight")) : 1), 0);

                }

            }

            float linearVelocity = Mathf.Round (((transform.position - lastLinearPosition) / Time.fixedDeltaTime).magnitude * 100f) / 100f;
            lastLinearPosition = transform.position;

            float angularVelocity = Mathf.Round ((transform.eulerAngles.y - lastAngularPosition) / Time.fixedDeltaTime * Mathf.Deg2Rad  * 100f) / 100f;
            lastAngularPosition = transform.eulerAngles.y;

            uiController.UpdateVelocities (linearVelocity, angularVelocity);


        }
    }

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision col){

        rigidbody.isKinematic = true;

        rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        rigidbody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;

        rigidbody.isKinematic = false;

    }
    public enum DriveModes{
        Tank,
        Mecanum
    }

    public void setDriveMode(){

        int index = PauseCanvas.transform.GetChild (1).GetComponent<Dropdown> ().value;

        if (index == 0) {
            driveMode = DriveModes.Tank;
        } else if (index == 1) {
            driveMode = DriveModes.Mecanum;
        }

        uiController.UpdateDriveMode (index == 0 ? "Tank" : "Mecanum");
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you move this Object? Please add some code!

Comment: @Programmer added code, this class controls the player's movement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When GameObject has `Rigidbody` and Collider and you want collision, do **not** move the Object by `transform.Translate` or rotate it with `transform.Rotate` or  `transform.RotateAround`. When you do this there will be no collision.

The right way to move GameObject with a `Rigidbody` and Collision is with the [`Rigidbody.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) function.

The correct way to rotate it is to use the [`Rigidbody.MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html) function.

---

Example of [`Rigidbody.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html):

```
float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
float v = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

Vector3 tempVect = new Vector3(h, 0, v);
tempVect = tempVect.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;
rb.MovePosition(transform.position + tempVect);
```

Example of [`Rigidbody.MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html):

```
Quaternion deltaRotation = Quaternion.Euler(eulerAngleVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
rb.MoveRotation(rb.rotation * deltaRotation);
```

You need to replace `transform.Translate`, `transform.Rotate` and `transform.RotateAround` with these.

Comment: I switched from using these functions because they weren't working exactly as I wanted, but the problem persists when I reverted to that code and tried again. I know you aren't supposed to do it this way, but it works in one scene and not in another, and I don't know why. I've added the github link to the project if you want to look at it in more detail. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It doesn't matter if it works sometimes or not. What I mentioned above is the problem and you have to fix it like I mentioned in my answer

Comment: Actually I just found the problem, there was a second collider interfering that was hidden in a child object. Not really sure that happened since it's a prefab. The movement and collisions do work fine though. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are welcome. Just to let you know, you are creating a buggy game. before you write more codes, fix that. The sooner you fix this, the better. If you don't fix it and release this as a game, you will get reports that collision is not working sometimes. Collision callback functions may not be called at anytime. This will be random.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I wouldn't normally do this but this is a simulation that will basically only be used by me so I don't have to worry about that kind of thing.

Comment: Ok. I was worried because I see this kind of issue on this site. Happy coding!